# Bash - While loop exit code 1

Tags: bash

I have a problem with one of my bash scripts. Here is code.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ENVIRONMENT=$1
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME=$2
TOKEN_AZURE=$3
TOKEN_GITHUB=$4
DATA_GOVERNANCE_NAME=$5
CURRENT_WORKING_DIR=$6
GIT_TIME_PERIOD=${7:-60 days}

if [ -z $2 ]; then echo "Environment name and the storage account name must be passed as a parameter" && exit 1; fi

echo "Filtering the repos to find out which should be deployed to blob containers workspace..."

less $CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/$DATA_GOVERNANCE_NAME/$ENVIRONMENT/data_ingestion_framework/Repos/Deployable_repos.json | jq -r '[.Repos[]  | select(.LOCATION[]=="STORAGE")]' >$CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/repos_filtered_blob.json

REPOS_COUNT=$(jq length $CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/repos_filtered_blob.json)

for containers in $(jq -r '[.Repos[] | select(.LOCATION[]=="STORAGE") | .PATH ] | unique | .[]' $CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/$DATA_GOVERNANCE_NAME/$ENVIRONMENT/data_ingestion_framework/Repos/Deployable_repos.json);
do
    echo "Clearing content of $containers blob"
    STRIPED_CONTAINER=$(echo $containers | sed -r "s|/?$||")
    if [ $STRIPED_CONTAINER == 'datagovernance' ];
    then
        az storage blob delete-batch --auth-mode login --account-name $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --source $STRIPED_CONTAINER --query '[::-1]' --delete-snapshots include
    else
        az storage blob delete-batch --auth-mode login --account-name $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --source $STRIPED_CONTAINER --query '[::-1]'
    fi
done

if [ $REPOS_COUNT -eq "0" ]; then echo "No repos meant for blob containers found" && exit 1; fi

echo "Repos meant for blob containers found: $REPOS_COUNT"

echo ""
REGEX="^https://(.*@)?"
declare -i i=0

while [ $REPOS_COUNT -gt 0 ]; do

    echo "Getting the repo name to be deployed..."

    REPO_NAME=$(jq -r .[$i].Name $CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/repos_filtered_blob.json)

    echo "Repository name: $REPO_NAME"

    echo "Checking if the repo should be deployed to $ENVIRONMENT environment..."
    echo "$ENVIRONMENT environment detected! Extracting the source branch name..."

    BRANCH_NAME=$(less $CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/repos_filtered_blob.json | jq -r '.['$i'].BRANCH')
    echo "Source branch name: $BRANCH_NAME"
    REPO_LINK=$(jq -r .[$i].Link $CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/repos_filtered_blob.json)

    echo "Repository LINK: $REPO_LINK"
    if $(echo $REPO_LINK | grep -q github.dxc.com);
    then
            echo "GitHub link detected!"
            ADJUSTED_LINK=$(echo $REPO_LINK | sed -r "s|$REGEX|https://$TOKEN_GITHUB@|g")
    else
            echo "Azure DevOps repository link detected!"
            ADJUSTED_LINK=$(echo $REPO_LINK | sed -r "s|$REGEX|https://$TOKEN_AZURE@|g")
    fi
    echo "Adjusted link: $ADJUSTED_LINK"
    REPO_SSH=$(jq -r .[$i].SSH $CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/repos_filtered_blob.json)

    echo ""
    CONTAINER_NAME=$(jq -r .[$i].PATH $CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/repos_filtered_blob.json | sed -r "s|/?$||")
    CLEAN_COPY=$(jq -r .[$i].CLEAN_COPY $CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/repos_filtered_blob.json)
    echo "Container name: $CONTAINER_NAME"

    echo "Cloning the source branch..."

    rm -rf $CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/Repos/$REPO_NAME
    git clone --branch $BRANCH_NAME --single-branch $ADJUSTED_LINK $CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/Repos/$REPO_NAME

    echo "Checking if the repository had recent commits..."
    cd $CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/Repos/$REPO_NAME

    if git log --date=relative --since "$GIT_TIME_PERIOD" | grep -q commit; 
    then
        echo "Repository edited in last $GIT_TIME_PERIOD, will proceed with copying..."
        cd ..
        echo "Saving the list of the contents..."
        if [ "$CLEAN_COPY" = "true" ];
        then
            if [ "$REPO_NAME" = "$DATA_GOVERNANCE_NAME" ]; 
            then
                find $REPO_NAME/$ENVIRONMENT/ | sed -r 's,^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\/){2},,' >contents.txt
            else
                find $REPO_NAME/ | sed 's,^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\/){1},,' >contents.txt
            fi
            # cat contents.txt
            echo "Deleting the pre-existing files from the container..."
            az storage blob delete-batch --auth-mode login --account-name $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --source $CONTAINER_NAME --query '[::-1]' 
        else
            echo "Skiping deleting the pre-existing files from the container.. "
        fi
        if [ "$REPO_NAME" = "$DATA_GOVERNANCE_NAME" ]; 
        then
            echo "Copying $ENVIRONMENT to datagovernance"
            az storage blob upload-batch --auth-mode login --account-name $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --destination $CONTAINER_NAME --source "$CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/Repos/$REPO_NAME/$ENVIRONMENT" --overwrite --no-progress
        else
            echo ""
            echo "Copying the files to the container..."
            az storage blob upload-batch --auth-mode login --account-name $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --destination $CONTAINER_NAME --source "$CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/Repos/$REPO_NAME" --overwrite --no-progress
        fi
    else
        echo "Repository not edited recently, will not copy..."
        echo ""
        cd ..
    fi
    ((i = i + 1))
    ((REPOS_COUNT = REPOS_COUNT - 1))

done
```

The problem with this script is that whenever I run whole run is going smoothly and perform everything that is required. However at the end it always throws error bellow.

```
##[error]The process '/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
##[error]Bash failed with error: The process '/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
```

I have spent quite few hours trying to debug this but i don't know what is cause of that error. Can error be caused by while loop itself?

Comment: Looks like an Azure CLI error to me (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/12164)), bash itself does not write `##[error]` to stdout. Maybe try [debugging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script) the script?

Comment: What's the last thing getting `echo`ed? This might give you an indication where it's going wrong.

Comment: I believe this might be issue with AZ CLI and AzureDevops. This error do appear when i run script manualy from my PC or Azure selfhosted Agent. Only when it's triggered via pipeline

Comment: `((REPOS_COUNT = REPOS_COUNT - 1))` is leaving the exit status 1 after the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: AND ... this is way too much code considering the ultimate problem. Please  read, review and take to heart the items on this page : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Skip the Version information at the top and search for the sections  labeled "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" . And for a more general view on this issue, please read [mcve] . Good luck.